# Why does not a try-catch block catch a child_process spawn exception due to invalid executable path in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, exception, try-catch, child-process, spawn

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process")

try{
    spawn("invalid/path/to/executable")
}catch(err){
    console.log("exception: ",err)
}
```

This code raises an error and the execution of the program stops. It never prints `exception:` so the catch block is not executed:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn invalid/path/to/executable ENOENT
```

When run with a valid path to an executable, the same code works.

What can I do to handle the case when the spawn fails due to ENOENT error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module fires `error` event and you can just add a listener for it.
You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error)

So, you can transform your code to:

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process")

const subprocess = spawn("invalid/path/to/executable")
subprocess.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Failed to start subprocess: ' + err);
});
```

Also, I suggest reading this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) by Samer Buna. He covered a lot of interesting topics about this module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was in the mindset that no code in a try block can do any damage and did not look at the spawn manual for error handling.